# Jquery Selectors for multipe slideToogle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I set my selector to be specific to each h1 and main within multiple repeated structure. I need to be able to click on a h1 and open the  contained on the same section as per html bellow. As per the javascript bellow please answer what var trigger and var content should be to accomplish the requirements.

```
    <section id="side_nav">
        <!-- Main -->
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Main Header</h1>
                <a href="#">Call to action</a>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div>
                    <p><span>content</span><span>content</span></p>
                    <p><span>content</span><span class="positive">content</span></p>   
                </div>  
            </main>
        </section>
        <!-- First sub  -->
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>First sub header</h1>
                <p>Content</p>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div>
                    <p><span>content</span><span>content</span></p>
                    <p><span>content</span><span>content</span></p>
                </div>          
            </main>
        </section>
        <!-- Second sub  -->
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Second sub header</h1>
                <p>content</p>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div>
                    <p><span>content</span><span>content</span></p>
                    <p><span>content</span><span>content</span></p>
                </div>        
            </main>
        </section>
        <!-- Third sub  -->
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Third sub header</h1>
                <p>content</p>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div>
                    <p><span>content</span><span>content</span></p>
                    <p><span>content</span><span>content</span></p>
                </div>         
            </main>
        </section>
    </section>
```

My current JS looks like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var trigger = $("h1");
        var content = $( "main" );

        trigger.click(function(){
            content.slideToggle( "slow" );
        });
    });
```

Here as JsFiddle with my current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/fLyy931s/

Comment: You need to stop changing people answers and saying they don't work... the reason no one is using the "content" variable outside of the click handler is because you lose scope at that point and it won't have the relational value to tnhe H1 you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reference `this` in your trigger function and then traverse the DOM to the content you are showing:

```
trigger.click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('main').slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Also you probably want some CSS to initially hide your `<main>` content:

```
main {
    display:none;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLyy931s/2/

Comment: It actually works but if I put the selector on a variable is breaks. :p

Comment: Often times when you create a `var` for a jQuery selector, i.e. `$( "main" )` you use a dollar sign to remind you that it's a jQuery object, not a string, like this: `$content`. Because in the `siblings()` function I'm passing a STRING.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're referring to *all* `<content>` elements in your documents instead of referring to the one next to your `<h1>`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var trigger = $("h1");

    trigger.click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('main').slideToggle( "slow" );
    });
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLyy931s/1/)

Comment: @ViniciusSantana You're not trying the code I provided.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('section').find('main').slideToggle( "slow" );
    });
});
```

the `.closest` method finds the closest parent that matches the selector, grabbing that you can find the main child and your functionality will always be relative to the structure.

To expand on why your "this doesn't work" comments are wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when you do this...
    var trigger=$('h1');
    //You are saying "grab every h1 on the page"

    //when you do this...
    var content=$('main');
    //you are grabbing EVERY "main" on the page

    //so when you do this
    trigger.click(function(){
      //you apply a click handler to every h1 on the page

      //now once in here when you reference "content" you are actually
      //referencing EVERY "main" on the page since you already assigned
      //that collection to a variable outside of the click handler

      //the reason we all used a variation of this:

        $(this).closest('section').find('main').slideToggle( "slow" );

      // is because $(this) now points to the specific h1 that was clicked
      // on, so by navigating the DOM using the available jQuery methods
      // we can actially get the "main" element that relates to the h1
    });
});
```

Basically you are carrying a global scope into a event handler and assuming it has some dynamic way to determine context. It may make a little more sense like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var triggers=$('h1');
    //let's call it "triggers" since this will actually return every h1 on the page.

    triggers.click(function(){
        //Grab the parent of the thing that was clicked on so we can find the
        //right content to toggle

        var context=$(this).closest('section');

        //When you send a second argument in to jQuery like this you tell
        // it where to look for the elements you've selected
        var content=$('main',context);

        //NOW you can use your variable knowing that you have the right
        //piece of content
        content.slideToggle( "slow" );
    });
});
```

Comment: You changed my code in your fiddle... this works exactly as designed

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you understand how scope works.

Comment: I didn't touch your fiddle. My reply had my fiddle and my questions was on how to have a variable holding the selector but your improved answer resolved that. Voted up.